# declare table variable inside function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my stored procedure, I have table variable with a lot of columns. Because I want to simplify the stored procedure I thought i could declare table variable in function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_DeclareMaterialTableVariable]
(
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    ... dozens of columns
)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
END
```

but i realized i don't know, how to use it. My idea was something like

```
select * 
into @table
from [dbo].[ufn_DeclareMaterialTableVariable]
```

but this is not gonna work, unless i use temporary table.

The second idea is to declare table with custom data type.

```
declare @table TABLE as CustomTableType
```

but this is also not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a table variable with the same shape as the TVF result, then use `INSERT INTO` not `SELECT INTO`, and remember to add brackets/parentheses to the end of the function name when invoking it, i.e. `Foo()` not just `Foo`:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    ... dozens of columns
);

// not best practice, but...
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ufn_DeclareMaterialTableVariable();

// better - be explicit about the columns of interest
INSERT INTO @Table (
    [Id],
    [Number],
    [Name],
    ... dozens of columns
)
SELECT
    [Id],
    [Number],
    [Name],
    ... dozens of columns
FROM dbo.ufn_DeclareMaterialTableVariable();
```

If you've declared a table type, then the syntax for declaring a variable of that type is the following (note no `TABLE` keyword);

```
DECLARE @Table CustomTableType;
```

That said, annoyingly, you can't declare the result type of a TVF to be a table type - i.e. you always have to declare the returned columns again, explicitly - which partially negates the point of the custom type in the first place, in this situation.

Comment: Thank you, the second approach is exactly what i need :)